# I have an issue with iPad orientation on first time loading or whenever I navigate back from my current page

Tags: css, ipad, orientation, media-queries

When I load the page in landscape, the page doesn't fit to the screen but it displays greater than the width. At the same time when I change the orientation to Portrait and double tap the screen, then change to landscape, the page fits exactly to the screen.
What I have to add? What I have missed out? Why its not diplaying exactly at the first load without double tap the screen.

**I used below:**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation: portrait){/*style starts...*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add meta `viewport tag` to your app `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

It looks like viewport problem.

Comment: This is great Pinal. I have implemented and now working exactly on first load itself on landscape, but some alignment issues on portrait orientation. Do I have to adjust styling from my side.

Comment: Change `min-device-width/max-device-width` to `min-width/max-width`.

Comment: The above modification doesn't made any changes. Still the portrait doesn't fix. Do i have to write separate for Portrait.

Comment: What device do you use? Please create a jsfiddle with full code example.